# Add magnetic declination to print composer

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, print-composer

Is it possible to let the QGIS print composer calculate the magnetic declination at the current map area and just display the value in the corner of the map? I have searched a lot but did not find any suitable solution...

Comment: There is a plugin to calculate it.  https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/MagneticDeclination/  You can then use that number to rotate an arrow or add text in your layout.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have already found this plugin - yet I didn't figure out how to automate it. As far as I understood I have to manually use the tool, before I can use the variable. Can you think of a way to perform this automatically, as soon as I open/use the print composer?

Comment: please [edit] your question with your additional information and a clear description of where you are currently stuck

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, there are plugins which allow this value to be calculated, or alternatively you can use an expression (and some complex logic) to retrieve the value from an api or service.

There is a open QEP for incorporating this into the core QGIS application: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/165